# Automatizacion de envio de correos desde C# y SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql, email, outlook

Tengo el siguiente metodo el cual me ayuda a enviar un correo a una persona:

```
public void SendMail()
        {
            dynamic oApp = null;
            dynamic oMsg = null;

            try
            {
                oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = oApp.Session;

                oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                // Agregar destinatarios
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;
                List<string> oTORecip = new List<string>();
        // Agregar copia oculta
                List<string> oBCCRecip = new List<string>();

                oTORecip.Add("Correo.destino@outlook.com");
                oBCCRecip.Add("Correo.oculto@outlook.com");

                foreach (string t in oTORecip)
                {
                    Outlook.Recipient oTORecipt = oRecips.Add(t);
                    oTORecipt.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo;
                    oTORecipt.Resolve();
                }

                foreach (string t in oBCCRecip)
                {
                    Outlook.Recipient oBCCRecipt = oRecips.Add(t);
                    oBCCRecipt.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
                    oBCCRecipt.Resolve();
                }

                // Ruta completa de la imagen
                string rutaImagen = "\\\\Dominio\\Reporte\\Plantilla\\Invitacion.jpg";

                // Establecer las propiedades básicas
                oMsg.Subject = "TestMail- " + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                oMsg.HTMLBody = "<html>" +
                    "<head>" +
                    "<title>TestMail</title>" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body style='background-color:#FFFFFF;'>" +
                    "<div style='font-family: Georgia, Arial; font-size:14px; '>" +
                    "<img src=\"" + rutaImagen + "\" alt=\"Descripción de la imagen\">" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";            

                // Obtener la cuenta deseada
                Outlook.Account account = GetOutlookAccount("Correo.Remitente@outlook.com", oApp);

                // Establecer la cuenta desde la cual se enviará el correo
                oMsg.SendUsingAccount = account;

                // Guardar el mensaje
                oMsg.Save();

                // Enviar el mensaje
                oMsg.Send();

                MessageBox.Show("Correo enviado con éxito.");
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error al enviar el correo: {e.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Liberar objetos
                if (oMsg != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oMsg);
                    oMsg = null;
                }
                if (oApp != null)
                {
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp);
                    oApp = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Este metodo me ayuda a solo mandarle a una persona el correo, pero me gustaria agregar una manera para que los correos a los que se mandará el mensaje se tomen de una tabla de mi base de datos en sql server, es decir que mi metodo vaya tomando cada uno de los correos de mi tabla y vaya mandando el mensaje dentro de un ciclo, de uno en uno hasta que se mande a todos, pero ¿Como puedo realizar esto?

Espero puedan ayudarme con este problema que tengo, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: "¿Como puedo realizar esto?" Existen miles de ejemplos en internet de conexión de sql server con c#, debes de realizar tu investigación previa. Si implementando tu solución tienes algún inconveniente, allí recurres a SO

Comment: creo te conviene utilizar SmtpClient